# Triangulation in periodically repeated 3D box

Tags: periodic-functions, triangulation

I have a set of points in a 3D box (rectangular parallelepiped), which is periodically repeated out of two its opposite sides. How do I find the Delaunay triangulation for this set of points?

Here is a 2D-case for the problem:

[image: 2D case]

Points are stored as being inside a rectangle. Regular Delaunay triangulation is given in the row 1. If repeated periodically out of left and right side, triangulation becomes different, as shown in the row 2.

My current guess is to repeat the box one only time in each direction and construct regular triangulation, as in the row 3. In this case, the part intersecting the original box is the same as in periodical triangulation.

But is this always true? Is this true for 3D case?

PS. I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgcsFR_DoA4) on the problem, but the guy is not clearly saying that repeating the set of points one time and constructing regular triangulation will always give the correct answer.